# How do Zip contains all the folder (and subfolder) within a single file?

Tags: algorithm, compression, zip

I am **NOT** asking for how compression works! I am known of (at least, have basic knowledge) algorithms like LZ and Huffman. My question is how to all files, and folder fit into the single zip file? Does it have some kind of delimeter to distinguish between files, and relative directory information appended to each block of information? Or there's something else happening ?

(I am tagging this post as compression, just not to lose the audience)

Comment: It's a container file format. Look at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ZIP-64_Internal_Layout.svg) for a rough overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [zip appnote](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) explains the format in detail.  A zip file consists of a series of entries, each with one file, followed by a central directory with information on the contents.  Each entry has a local header and optional trailer with much of the same information.  Each descriptor in the local header or central directory entry has the full path name, including directories.

Comment: Thanks. I Corrected the spelling too :)